# Routes from frontend shown as insecure in https website

Tags: javascript, vue.js, https, vue-component

I created a webpage using vue.js and on backend node.js.
When I access the main page ( https://example.test ) I got secure info on my browser, but once I go to other links ( https://example.test/dashboard ) I got an insecure connection.

```
"devServer": {
    allowedHosts: ['example.test'],
    host: "0.0.0.0",
    port: 443,
    server : {
      type: "https",
      options: {
      key: fs.readFileSync('/usr/app/key.pem'),
      cert: fs.readFileSync('/usr/app/cert.pem')
    }},
    hot: true
  }
```

Is there any configuration that I'm missing in vue.config.js or I'm missing something in router/index.js?

```
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
    {
        path: "/sign-in",
        name: "signIn",
        component: SignIn,
        meta: {
            requiresNotAuth: true
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/dashboard",
        name: "dashboard",
        component: Dashboard,
        meta: {
            requiresAuth: true
        }
    }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes
})
```

*UPDATE*
security in https://example.test:
[image]

Security in https://example.test/dashboard:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's not because of other links/assets on the `dashboard` path? Check the `security` tab in your browser devtools.

Comment: Hello , I updated the question with the security info. It seems that api (port 3443) is unsecure for some routes , and not unsecure in index page. Then maybe the problem is in api node ?